# Romanian Visa Rules for New Zealand citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, romania, new-zealand-citizens

I came to Europe via Estonia, where I spent two months (entering via the Schengen Zone), after which I have come to Romania. My visas:

[image]

I have come here for work-related purposes, so I am in a transition period before my work visa will be applied for. However, during this time, I need to legally stay within the country.

I have found it very difficult to find information regarding the Romanian visa and how long it is, whether or not I can do a 'border-run' and re-enter Romania, etc.

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Romania mostly applies the same rules as the Schengen area, as part of their preparation to eventually join it. The rules detailed on the website of the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) are nearly identical and even the forms or the stamps (technically not a visa) are almost the same as those of Schengen countries (including Estonia, as you can see on your own passport).

So the [90/180 rules](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) applies and it's not possible to do a border run. If you have stayed 90 days (or thereabouts) in Romania and are not able to get a long-stay visa/permit, you will have to stay out of the country for another 90 days. However, because Romania is not part of the Schengen area, “out of the country“ also includes Schengen countries.